# ReSharper and CMake conflict

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, resharper

We have a Visual Studio solution that uses CMake for project management. This means the solution folder is under CMake's control, and when CMake detects changes it regenerates the folder.

ReSharper stores its options files in the solution folder. You can tell it to import a layer from somewhere else, but that "somewhere else" is stored in, yes, you guessed it, the solution folder, which can be trashed at any time by CMake.

Is there any way around this? Ideally tell ReSharper "load your options from this file here, don't look in the solution"?

(Just want to say it wasn't my choice to use CMake, I don't know very much about it so it may be there's a solution there).

Comment: Is the solution generated by cmake? Normally, the solution is only regenerated when any of the cmake files have changed. It doesn't matter if any other application is storing files in your binary folder.

Comment: Apparently, talking to one of the other devs here, CMake can occasionally get confused when you update a library. Hence the need to clear its cache. Simply removing the folder contents also confuses CMake, the entire folder has to be purged!

Comment: what if you do `file(CREATE_LINK "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.../${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.sln.DotSettings" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.../${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.sln.DotSettings" SYMBOLIC)` and `file(CREATE_LINK "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.sln.DotSettings.user" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.sln.DotSettings.user" SYMBOLIC)` in your CMakeLists.txt? My hypothesis is that that would make the actual content be stored somewhere that doesn't get wiped, and then reconfiguration wipes the solution directory along with the symlinks, but then the symlinks get regenerated. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @starball that will probably be fine under Linux but not Windows? We have discussed with Jetbrains now, and it seems the best solution is to copy out the settings to temp before a destructive CMake operation, do the thing, then copy back afterwards. Seems kinda silly, but as good as we're going to get.

Comment: @jg_at_vividq why wouldn't it work under windows? CMake supports Windows. Usually when a function has specific different behaviour on a specific platform, it documents it. Please, just try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R# always stores solution settings in a `.DotSettings` file next to the solution. One approach would be to have a custom logic in the CMake config to recreate the `.DotSettings` file when you generate a Visual Studio solution. You can either copy the settings file from somewhere else, or even better, create a dumb `.DotSettings` file that will just import the real `.DotSettings` file from another location in your project.

You can also try using the built-in CMake support in Visual Studio. If you open your CMake project file directly instead of the generated solution, R# will store solution settings in the `Folder.DotSettings` file in the root project folder.

Comment: Can you explain the import method?  That sounds like something that CMake could create and place in the CMake bin (build) folder next to the solution while keeping the "real" one outside of build in the source control but I can't find any information about how to do it.

Comment: Check the documentation on how to [add a custom settings layer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html#addCustom).